# Websphere Liberty- java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.websphere.ssl.SSLException

Tags: java, spring, ssl, websphere-8, websphere-liberty

I am getting the following error while instantiating a web application on WebSphere Liberty beta. The application starts successfully on WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.websphere.ssl.SSLException
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:93)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:91)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.prepare(J9VMInternals.java:490)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:231)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1002)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:975)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:633)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:2381)
    ... 1 more
```

Please provide any pointers that could help me resolve this. Here is server.xml for liberty server:

```
<server description="new server">

    <!-- Enable features -->


    <!-- To access this server from a remote client add a host attribute to 
        the following element, e.g. host="*" -->

    <featureManager>
        <feature>beanValidation-1.1</feature>
        <feature>jdbc-4.0</feature>
        <feature>jaxb-2.2</feature>
        <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
        <feature>jaxws-2.2</feature>       
        <feature>distributedMap-1.0</feature>   

        <feature>servlet-3.0</feature>
        <feature>ssl-1.0</feature>
    </featureManager>
     <include location="GeneratedSSLInclude.xml"/>

    <httpEndpoint httpPort="9081" httpsPort="9444" id="defaultHttpEndpoint"/>

    <logging consoleLogLevel="INFO" traceSpecification="javax.validation *=info:javax.validation.*=finest"/>
    <library id="JAX-RS2">
        <fileset dir="C:\workspace_eclipse\JAX-RS2\lib" includes="*.jar" scanInterval="5"/>

    </library>

    <applicationMonitor updateTrigger="mbean"/>

    <enterpriseApplication id="ProductServiceEAR" location="ProductServiceEAR-1.0.ear" name="ProductServiceEAR">
     <classloader privateLibraryRef="JAX-RS2"/>
    </enterpriseApplication>


     <keyStore id="defaultKeyStore" password="{xor}AXnKzg6TSmwMw=="/> -->
</server>
```

EDIT: The exception is thrown while generating spring jax-ws client bean. My application-context.xml file for the webservice client looks like:

```
<bean id="searchWebServiceClient"
        class="org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean">
        <property name="serviceInterface"
            value="au.com.test.search.SearchWebServiceClient" />
        <property name="wsdlDocumentUrl" value="classpath:/ServiceSchemas/involvedPartyManagement/involvedPartyManagement/SearchWebService_v2.wsdl" />
        <property name="namespaceUri"
            value="http://www.test.com.au/gn/involvedPartyManagement/services/SearchWebService/v2/WS0234" />
        <property name="serviceName"
            value="SearchWebService" />
        <property name="endpointAddress" value="${WS0234v2}" />     
    </bean>
```

Comment: _[Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the **desired behavior**, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)_

Comment: Hi Micky, this should not be linked to code. May be including any jars in the liberty server or setting some configuration parameter.

Comment: OK.  It wasn't quite clear _which application_ it was.  Maybe one for the Websphere support forums then considering it is `beta`?

Comment: Which jre do you use?

Comment: IBM J9 VM (build 2.6, JRE 1.7.0 Windows 7 amd64-64 Compressed References 20130421_145945 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)

Comment: liberty installation contains com.ibm.ws.ssl_1.0.8.jar file in lib dir. This jar contains com.ibm.websphere.ssl.SSLException class.

Comment: Are you using JVM provided with full WebSphere or downloaded separately for Liberty?

Comment: I had downloaded jdk7 separately. I am using the same jdk with liberty and websphere full profile.

Answer (score 0):

SSL by default is not enabled on Liberty. Did you add `ssl-1.0` feature to your `server.xml` and configured according to this page [Enabling SSL communication for the Liberty profile](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_sec_ssl.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F3-3-11-0-4-1-0&lang=en).

PS. Add your `server.xml` file to the question.

If you are using JVM from full WebSphere, you need to change SSL factories.
Create `jvm.options` file in the server directory with the following content:

`-Djava.security.properties=./myjava.security`

Create `myjava.security` file in the server directory with the following content (empty properties):

```
 ssl.SocketFactory.provider=
 ssl.ServerSocketFactory.provider=
```

Alternatively, test your application with Liberty running on Oracle JVM.

Comment: I have added server.xml. ssl-1.0 is included in the enabled features list and configured as well. I am not using https to access my application.

Comment: @pawindergupta If you are not accessing your application, then maybe your application is accessing something over SSL?

Comment: updated jvm.options and created ./myjava.security. Still getting the same exception- java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.websphere.ssl.SSLException

Comment: Also tried on Oracle JVM. It is also throwing the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
    You need to add transportSecurity feature type in server.xml as:

    <feature>transportSecurity-1.0</feature>

    and also add SSL configuration (see below a prescription from server.xml) so that it could create SSLContext using SPI in your code -- something like:
    JSSEHelper.getInstance().getSSLContext("sslContextName", null, null);

    <!-- SSL config -->
    <keyStore id="sslKeyStore" location="${ssl.keystore.location}" password="${ssl.password}"/>
    <keyStore id="sslTrustStore" location="${ssl.truststore.location}" password="${ssl.password}"/>

    <ssl id="sslContextName" sslProtocol="TLSv1" securityLevel="HIGH" keyStoreRef="sslKeyStore" trustStoreRef="sslTrustStore" clientAuthenticationSupported="true" >
         <outboundConnection host="${some.service.host}" port="${some.service.port}" />
    </ssl>

    Remember - you need to run your app under Liberty profile. If not then you put it inside try()/catch() block -- something like:

    try {
         return JSSEHelper.getInstance().getSSLContext("sslContextName", null, null);
        } 
        catch (SSLException | NoClassDefFoundError e) {
         return SSLContextBuilder
        .create()
        .loadTrustMaterial(
Paths.get(webServiceClientConfig.getTrustStore()).toFile(), webServiceClientConfig.getSslPassword().toCharArray())
                        .build();
            }
```